# Update the first table by selecting data and performing calculation from the second table - Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables in oracle, table 1 and table 2

Table 1

```
     mm/yy     order-id     cost   currency    
   -------    ---------    ------  -------- 
    01/17        1         25       pound
    03/17        2         30       euro
    04/17        3         16       pound
    05/17        4         14       pound
    06/17        5         10       euro
    06/17        6         10       usd
```

Table 2

```
    dd/mm/yy        currency   Conversion_rate_to_USD
   ------------  ----------    -------------------- 
    01/01/17        pound          1.24
    02/01/17        pound          1.23
    03/01/17        pound          1.26
    ........        ......         ....
    ........        ......         ....
    ........        ......         ....
    01/04/17        pound          1.24
    02/04/17        pound          1.23
    03/05/17        pound          1.26
    ........        ......         ....
    ........        ......         ....
    ........        ......         ....
    01/03/17        euro           1.15
    02/03/17        euro           1.16
    03/06/17        euro           1.11
    01/06/17        euro           1.07
```

I would like to retrieve cost converted in USD (using average conversion cost for the month from table 2) for each row in table 1.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  In addition, you should specify the types of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that the "date" columns are indeed stored as a dates.  Date functions differ across databases, but this (or a slight variant) should work in most.

To get the average per month from table2:

```
select year(ddmmyy), month(ddmmyy), currency, avg(Conversion_rate_to_USD)
from table2
group by year(ddmmyy), month(ddmmyy), currency;
```

To do the conversion use this as a subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (t1.cost * t2.avg_c) as cost_in_usd
from table1 t1 join
     (select year(ddmmyy) as yr, month(ddmmyy) as mon, currency,
             avg(Conversion_rate_to_USD) as avg_c
      from table2
      group by year(ddmmyy), month(ddmmyy), currency
     )  t2
     on t2.yr = year(t1.mmyy) and t2.mon = year(t1.mmyy) and
        t2.currency = t1.currency;
```